# SQL Insert Statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.KalenderDBconnect);

SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
     "INSERT into KalenderDB values ('" + tb_name + "','" + tb_Ort + "','" + tb_Event + "','" + tb_Notiz + "','" + teilgenommen + "','" + date + "')");

connection1.Open();
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection1.Close();
```

Can somebody say, why the `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't work? I can't find the problem .

Comment: How about *you* tell us *how* it doesn't work first? That would give us a much better starting point to help you. Also it looks like you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I would recommend you do a couple of things for starters wrap the SQL Connection and SQL Command code around a `using(){}` also change the insertCommand to use Parameters, also wrap the ExecuteNonQuery around a `try{}catch(SqlException sqlEx){}`

Answer (score 8):

Your connection and command aren't linked together.

Try something like the following:

```
connection1.Open();
insertCommand.Connection = connection1;
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection1.Close();
```

Also, as someone commented on your question, this is prone to SQL injection. You should be using parameters.

[Here's some MSDN documentation on parameters.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I forgot to mention, and I don't feel that it's worth editing my comment again, you can also add the connection into one of the overloaded constructors of the `SqlCommand` object. Also, it's highly recommended to add a `try/catch` block around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

SqlCommand take 2 arguments

1. Query
2. Connection Name

   SqlCommand objSql = new SqlCommand("Your Query",ObjectSqlConnection);